# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer to say they accept/decline the nomination. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following their acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://korean.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://korean.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Any idea on the timescale for these? Or are there other milestones we need to achieve first? Thanks.

Comment: @topomorto There is nothing further to be done on your end. Pro tems should be appointed ASAP. I will see what the holdup is and see that an announcement is posted naming the selections. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure there's no rush - we've been pretty civilised so far - but if traffic picks up it could be useful if someone here is able to do a bit of tidying. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]

I (Vladhagen) would be willing to volunteer as a moderator for the site.

- I have been active with this site in all of its stages. Area 51 Definition onward.
- Next to Ranthony, I currently have the most reputation on the private beta. This shows I have been able to provide relevant answers to a variety of questions, as well as ask questions of value.
- I have a degree in Korean (B.A.) and spent two years living in South Korea.
- I have been active on several other Stack Exchange sites. Mathematics and Academia are my main sites after Korean.

Answer (score 10):

[**topomorto**](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/64/topo-morto)

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I am happy to nominate topo morto as a candidate who:

- is one of the most active members on Korean Language Beta Stack Exchange since the beginning.
- knows how to ask and answer a question with proper examples and reference.
- has experience on other Stack Exchange sites such as [Music Fans Beta Stack Exchange](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/16/topo-morto)
- actively participates in community-building activities on Meta.

---

Thanks, happy to **accept** this nomination. Please bear in mind I am not a strong Korean speaker so I come here with more of a learner's perspective. However, I do have a strong personal interest in the success of this site. There are already some great users here and whoever is moderating, if we co-operate like we have been doing so far, I hope we can do well.

Comment: Lol you guys are nominating each other :P

Comment: I'm all for this!

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

I would like to volunteer myself for moderating the Korean StackExchange

I have been with this site even before it's proposal phase (committed to the previous iteration of the Korean stackexchange proposal which sadly did not make it), proposed and committed to the current iteration as well as worked towards bringing it to beta stage

I am fairly experienced with stackexchange as I use it to find solutions to my problems all the time, so am well acquainted with how it works. I have a decent amount of experience with using Korean and English as well.

Area51 activities:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083?phase=commitment
Participation in other sites:  http://stackexchange.com/users/360092/user17915

Comment: Due to the difference in username I didn't realise at first that you were our esteemed proposer, user13267 !

Answer (score 3):

[**choco_addicted**](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/45)

[image]

[image]

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/7757008.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/7757008)

#### Notes:

I would like to suggest choco_addicted as one of our moderator. I think that (s)he would be a suitable candidate for the following reasons:

- (S)he is experienced with the way the network works (1 Marshal, 2 Steward, 5 Reviewer and more than mid-way to the copy editor badge)
- (S)he is present from the beginning on this site and is an active user.
- (S)he is a native speaker which is also important because (s)he will be able to moderate content in Korean with more ease than a traditional learner. Moreover, I think that if the website wants to promote bilingualism we should have moderators representing the languages used on this site.

---

### Declined

I reject this nomination, because my communication skill using English is not so good... That's a reason that I participate per-site meta rarely. Thanks for nominating me anyway.

Comment: Because I can't edit this answer, I leave a comment. I reject this nomination, because my communication skill using English is not so good... That's a reason that I participate per-site meta rarely. Thanks for nominating me anyway.

Comment: @Rathony Partially yes. The **edit** button is blocked-the color of it is light grey in PC, and is not shown in mobile.

Comment: @choco someone has already edited this answer and it's approval is pending